# How do I escape unicode character 0x1F in xml?

Tags: xml, unicode

I need to write a text with the unicode character 0x1F in a utf-8 document (it is not an allowed character in xml). Is there a way to escape it, or do I have to discard it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do it in XML 1.1 (but is discouraged):

```
&#31;
```

It isn't supported at all in XML 1.0. A workaround is to base-64 encode the text containing the character.

Comment: Well, that is the same thing, but it is just as illegal.

xmllint for example:
test.xml:2: parser error : xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 31

Comment: can you please explain it. how can i use &#31; while parsing the xml which contains  0x1f char

Answer (score 3):

Using 0x1F XML is illegal (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets).
so there is no way to do it, except from encoding it yourself in some way. base-64 (as proposed), or url encode, or any other option that the xml does not understand.
It is the same problem as storing binary data in xml.