# Why does the XML serializer throw invalid character exception when character is inside CDATA?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are “control” characters illegal in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml)
>   [Saving an escape character 0x1b in an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134438/saving-an-escape-character-0x1b-in-an-xml-file)

This throws an ArgumentException:

```
    var c = '\x1A';

    var xml = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
                new XElement("test", new XCData(c.ToString()))
            );

    var foo = xml.ToString(); // ArgumentException
```

Why is .Net throwing this exception? I'm wrapping the illegal character in CDATA, so I would have thought that illegal characters would be handled for me.  This is also the case for a bunch of other characters (e.g. 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1F).

How do you work around this problem?

Comment: See these questions: [Saving an escape character 0x1b in an XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134438/saving-an-escape-character-0x1b-in-an-xml-file) and [Why are “control” characters illegal in XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml). Workaraund would be to use Base64 encoding before saving into an XML.

Comment: @oleksii You should turn this into an answer, because it's the correct response.

Comment: @Bevan: No, actually the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think SecurityElement.Escape will work because \x1A is a control code -- there's no valid xml entity to substitute.

See this [list of valid XML characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) for a bit more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Try storing your xml data as escaped data by using SecurityElement from System.Security  namespace.  More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
string xmlData = SecurityElement.Escape(xmlData);
```

Invalid XML characters can be written by creating the XDocument with XmlWriterSettings set with the CheckCharacters property set to false. This will then replace them with numeric character such as & #0; -- & #0x1F.   See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73083/Common-Pitfalls-in-System-Xml-4-0) article for more details.  Also as alternative you can call some cleanup xml method such as [this one.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1688373.aspx/1)

Comment: That doesn't work. I still get an ArgumentException for character \x1A even after using SecurityElement.Escape.

Comment: can you please show how you used it in your context

Comment: Control characters are not permitted in XML no matter what.