# How can I catch this XmlException thrown from third party library?

Tags: c#, exception, exchangewebservices

I'm using the Exchange Web Services managed API and about once a day it throws an `XmlException` that I have no idea how to catch. Here are the exception details.

```
System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled
  Message="'', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1."
  Source="System.Xml"
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=1
  SourceUri=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String[] args)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Int32 pos, Char invChar)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read(XmlNodeType nodeType)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.InternalReadElement(XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String localName, XmlNodeType nodeType)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.ReadStartElement(XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String localName)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader ewsXmlReader)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingServiceRequestBase.ParseResponses(Object state)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
  InnerException:
```

From the stacktrace I don't see anything that would allow me to catch and fix the issue.

How can I catch this?

Comment: what does the xml you're sending look like?

Comment: Do you want to catch that specific exception or on catching that exception you want to rectify that problem or you want some work-around so that the exception doesn't occur?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran: I am not sending XML. The XML is being returned by Exchange.

Comment: @SivaGopal: Yes, I would like that catch that specific exception because the XML is being returned by our Exchange server, which I have no control over.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693153/what-is-character-0x1f should help you fix the bug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML library doesn't support the `0x1F` char, which is the *unit separator* char.

What you can do is escape all occurrences of this specific char **before** your stream/XML file/whatever/ is processed by your XML library.
See [How do I escape unicode character 0x1F in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170270/how-do-i-escape-unicode-character-0x1f-in-xml)

See [allowed character ranges for XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets).

Comment: My apologies on not being very clear. The issue is caused by the EWS library parsing the XML returned by Exchange *without* sanitizing it. Because all of this is done within the library I don't know how to catch it.