# How to round-trip "invalid XML characters" - aren't character references valid/applicable?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement, invalid-characters

The following two code samples demonstrates this issue I am encountering where "invalid characters" are not encoded or decoded.

```
var elm = new XElement("foo", "\x12")
elm.ToString();
// ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x12, is an invalid character.
```

Likewise, parsing

```
var elm2 = XElement.Parse("<foo>&#x0012;</foo>");
// XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x12, is an invalid character ..
```

This is causes unexpected exceptions in unexpected cases -

How can I "resolve" this such that the XML is always properly encoded without exception? How can this problem be generally dealt with?

If I *must* preserve these "invalid characters" in a round-trip, is there a standard method of doing so *without* a custom encoding (eg. base64) process?

Also, I am surprised to see that using an XML entity did not fix the issue - *isn't encoded encoded?* Is this [a difference between XML versions or merely some fundamental XML limitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170270/how-do-i-escape-unicode-character-0x1f-in-xml)

---

In this case it would be OK to simply drop the invalid XML characters, *but* don't wish to perform the action manually for *every* text node inserted into the XElement structure.

This isn't an XElement only issue, although answers can rely on XElement being used, as online validation sites also reject the XML in the second case.

Comment: I think you might need an XCData element for these types of values.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - you'll still get 500 internal server error even if you try to wrap invalid characters. I believe some of the classes in .Net will allow to add such text but still properly fail reading it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087648/xml-invalid-characters-when-creating-cdata-node-from-unicodestring for link to the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make valid XML document with invalid characters which is roughly 0-31 for XML 1.0 and just 0 for XML 1.1 (but System.Xml *does not* support this standard). Complete list can be found in specification, or Wikipedia [Valid characters in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML).

Recommended way of dealing with such information which is essentially "binary data" is to Base64 encode it.